# Convert SDF database to MDF

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

I have this SQL Server CE database which I would like to convert to SQL Server 2008 database because I want it to be accessible through the network. I am using SQL Server 2008 Express and VB9.

Any idea?

Comment: This other question has better answers, but both should be kept.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way would be to go into SQL Management Studio (I think it can connecto to SDF files?) and right click on it and in actions there will be a script database to text file. That will give you SQL scripts to create the schema, then you can create them in SQL 2008.

Comment: Sure you can open SDF files in SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on which version of SQL Server Management Studio you using. If you using the SQL Server 2005 Management Studio Express, make sure you download the one with Service Pack2 from this [link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6053c6f8-82c8-479c-b25b-9aca13141c9e&DisplayLang=en) and not [this one](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en). The full version of Management Studio 2005 does support sdf files. I can't comment on the 2008 Express version though.